# How to link a subdomain in Plesk to an Elastic IP in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, plesk, plesk-onyx

I'm building a project in AWS. But the subdomain is in Plesk. And I don't want to move the whole domain from Plesk to AWS. The situation:

- example.com - this is in Plesk
- one.example.com - this is also in Plesk
- two.example.com - I just want this subdomain to be linked to AWS elatic IP

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't already have one you should [add a subdomain to Plesk](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/12.5/customer-guide/websites-and-domains/domains-and-dns/adding-subdomains.65180/) then set it's DNS configuration to AWS nameserver ([add domain in AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/get-a-domain/)) or directly to your server IP.